# 425 Rejected data connection from foreign address

Tags: windows, ftp, ftp-client

I am having problems right now and my server hosting provider can't fix this.

When I open, save, delete a file I am getting a 425 error.

FileZilla Log:

```
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Status: Connecting to ***.***.***.**:2121...
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Response: 220 Multicraft 2.1.1 FTP server
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Command: USER **************@gmail.com.3503
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Response: 331 Username ok, send password.
2017-05-24 16:04:24 4812 1 Command: PASS ********
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response: 230 Login successful
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Command: SYST
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Command: FEAT
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response: 211-Features supported:
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  EPRT
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  EPSV
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  MDTM
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  MLST type*;perm*;size*;modify*;unique*;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  SIZE
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  TVFS
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response:  UTF8
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Response: 211 End FEAT.
2017-05-24 16:04:25 4812 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Response: 200 OK
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Command: OPTS MLST type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Response: 200 MLST OPTS type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Status: Logged in
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Command: PWD
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory.
2017-05-24 16:04:26 4812 1 Command: TYPE I
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Response: 200 Type set to: Binary.
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Command: PASV
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Response: 227 Entering passive mode (172,106,203,31,157,129).
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Command: MLSD
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Response: 150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2017-05-24 16:04:27 4812 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
2017-05-24 16:04:56 4812 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/plugins"...
2017-05-24 16:04:56 4812 1 Command: CWD plugins
2017-05-24 16:04:56 4812 1 Response: 250 "/plugins" is the current directory.
2017-05-24 16:04:56 4812 1 Command: PWD
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Response: 257 "/plugins" is the current directory.
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Command: PASV
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Response: 227 Entering passive mode (172,106,203,31,195,123).
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Command: MLSD
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Response: 150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Response: 425 Rejected data connection from foreign address 122.3.233.21:60116.
2017-05-24 16:04:57 4812 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your local IP address keeps changing.

And the FTP server won't accept data connections from different IP address than the one that originally opened the FTP connection.

There's nothing you can do about it, except for fixing the IP address. *What is beyond scope of Stack Overflow. For that question, go to [su]. But make sure you share there some information, that can be used to help you. Your post does not say anything about your connection.*